# How force the widget's size in a box with Gtk 3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I'm making a program that is supposed to have a principal *textview* (see [textview](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textview.html#the-view)) where the user is supposed to write and a console, where the program is supposed to return the errors messages. So the console should be a little smaller than the text editor.
I also have a toolbar on the top of the window for the user to access the tools of my program and for editing the text.
To do that, I created a global box, where I put the tool bar, the textview and the console (which is also a textview object) using the `pack_start` attribute (`self.global_box.pack_start(self.console))`)

The toolbar is correctly placed (I put a button so it can have a length, and it works), but the rest of the space is **homogeneously** taken by the console and the textview, whereas I would like the console to take only a little space of my window.
How can I obligate my console to take only, for example, 20 pixels of my window? or to set a percentage of my window only for the textview?

[image: here is a screenshot of the window, so you can have an idea of what I'm talking about.]

EDIT:
The question is similar but its the solution didn't work for me.
Here is the code:

```py
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self,title='Text editor')
        self.maximize()
        self.global_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(self.global_box)

        self.create_textview()
        self.create_console()

    def create_textview(self):
        self.scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolled_window.set_hexpand(True)
        self.scrolled_window.set_vexpand(True)
        self.global_box.pack_start(self.scrolled_window, True, True, 0)

        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.scrolled_window.add(self.textview)
        self.tag_found = self.textbuffer.create_tag('found',background='yellow')

    def create_console(self):
        self.console_scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.console_scrolled_window.set_hexpand(True)
        self.console_scrolled_window.set_vexpand(True)
        self.global_box.pack_start(self.console_scrolled_window, False, False, 0)
        # ^ HERE the first one is expand argument, second one is irrelevant (the fill one)

        self.console = Gtk.TextView()
        self.console_scrolled_window.add(self.console)
        self.console.set_editable(False)
```

The problem is on the line where there is the comment HERE.

Comment: Do you want the amount of space between the two halves to be adjusted by the user? In that case, use GtkPaned. Otherwise, please show your code.

Comment: @oldtechaa yes, but in Gtk 3, the pack_start method takes exactly 4 arguments, one of them is expand. I tried to modified it, but it's still not working...

Comment: @andlabs no, I won't to able the user to change the size of the console.

Comment: I second andlabs on this. We need to see your code. Also, please show what you tried for `expand`. The `expand` parameter is _definitely_ what you need.

Comment: @oldtechaa I was adding it :)

Comment: Why do you have the console set to hexpand and vexpand = True if you don't want it to expand? Normally, you should never even need those functions if you're using boxes. The boxes will handle expanding for you. Also, in the future, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with any question when you ask it.

Comment: @oldtechaa I don't really know why do I need to use them, I reed at the doc that I just have to put them to get a scrolled window...

Comment: @oldtechaa well, I tryed to remove them and... it works!!! thanks a lot, it really helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `set_hexpand` and `set_vexpand` to `True`, which means they will expand. Remove those, and it will work properly.